# Can logon script be assigned to a user in a windows machine which is not a part of domain through powershell?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, powershell

This is the suggested way to add a logon script to a local user in Windows. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908.aspx

Edited:

I also found the following : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771314.aspx

Is it possible to add a logon script to a user through Local Users and Groups tab in Computer Management using powershell?

Update :

I am able to copy the script file to the location -\%COMPUTERNAME%\C$\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Star‌​t Menu\Programs\Startup' and it runs successfully. But in the local user properties I am not able to set the value of the attribute 'Logon script' to the desired value.

Comment: The duplicate question that this one was closed against no longer exists. There is NO duplicate.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're wanting to assign a script using PowerShell, vs the local group policy editor? As in, the script will assign the startup script?

Comment: Actually I want to do the script assignment through powershell script and not manually through local group policy editor. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I put my logon scripts in this folder.

```
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logon
```

So to answer

```
Copy-Item 'C:\temp\MyLogonScript.ps1' -destination 'C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logon'
#
```

Edit:  To install a logon script `per user` remotely, use this command.  Don't forget to edit the %COMPUTERNAME% and %username%

```
Copy-Item 'C:\temp\MyLogonScript.ps1' -destination '\\%COMPUTERNAME%\C$\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Star‌​t Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: if it fails, we'll need to add a snip to create the folder structure.

Comment: Hi Knuckle.. I have found a different way to add the logon script.Rather than adding the script to the group policy the script can be added to the user. I have edited my post with the link having the steps to perform the operation. Can this be done through powershell?

Comment: Change destination, `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: This worked fine.Thanks. But is it possible to do the same remotely?

Comment: So you want to loop through a list of names from a text file ? We can copy the file over the $admin shares `\\$SERVERNAMEVARIABLE\C$\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: No.I don't want to loop through a list of names.I just want to assign the logon script to a user on a remote machine.

Comment: In that case, I'd just throw that C$ path into your destination.  Updated the answer retro-actively

Comment: I have put the command into a script and then I am running the script file remotely.So that is working fine. I am facing an issue.I have updated the question.